# Перенос строки после записи

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет.
Такая проблема:
Есть 2 скрипта(1 это главный 2 это скрипт обновления)
код Апдейтера

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def parsetext_old():
    url_old = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/'
    r = requests.get(url_old)
    with open('temp_update.txt', 'w') as output_file:
      output_file.write(r.text)
    output_file.close()
    print('Downloaded')
def parse_unstable():
    url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('test.upd', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.text)
    print('Downloaded')
def backup():
    exist_script = open('server.py', 'r')
    tovalid = exist_script.read()
    exist_script.close()
    backup_s = open('server_bak.py', 'w')
    backup_s.write(str(tovalid))
    print('Backup Complete!')
def update():
    script = open('server.py', 'w')
    update_f = open('test.upd', 'r')
    upd_text = update_f.read()
    script.write(upd_text)
    print('Update Complete')
    update_f.close()
    script.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
#First Parse code
    parse_unstable()
    backup()
    update()
```

Ссылки скрыл)
Он скачивает текст с сайта и пишет в файл(там все ок!)
А сама проблема после записи в главный файл.

```
if DEBUG == 1:

    g = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    g.connect(("gmail.com",80))

    print(g.getsockname()[0])

    ssdd = g.getsockname()[0]

    g.close()

today = datetime.time(datetime.now())
```

В итоге после каждой строки добавляется ненужный перенос строки(
Как исправить?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как догадаться, какой у вас файл "главный". Я только вижу, что вы читаете и пишете всё в текстовом режиме, по идее, если оба действия делать в одном режиме, такой проблемы быть не должно. Но можете попробовать читать и писать в двоичном режиме - "rb", "wb".

Comment: Как именно выглядит "ненужный перевод строки"? Пустая строчка?